# Alternate function for openssl_public_encrypt in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, openssl, public-key-encryption

I have both public.key and private.key  both files include with string key.
i have implement encryption and decryption in PHP ill add the code below.

now i want to do the same thing in c#(encryption and decryption) same way that i implement with php(**the way should be openssl_public_encrypt method did** - because otherwise finally i sent this encrypt value as post request if that encrypt method did not matched to the way i did in php that will give a error saying my encrypt value misses some parameters-means my encryption algorithm is incorrect )

i tried boncycastle.crypto but algo is different i think,

this is the php code ->

```
$sensitiveData = $this->merchantcode.'|'.$order_id.'|'.$amountInc.'|'.$this->returnurl;
$public_key ="uuEks4FXTiLU2obIpTNIpqhjgiUhtjW4Si8cKLoT7RThyOvUadsgYWejLg2i0BVz+
           QC6F7pilEfaVSL/UgGNeNdMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCW8KV72IMdhE/wIDAQAB";

 $public_key_splitted = wordwrap($public_key, 64, "\n", true); 

$publicKey = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
$public_key_splitted
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOD;

$encrypted = '';
if (!openssl_public_encrypt($sensitiveData, $encrypted, $publicKey)) 
die('Failed to encrypt data'); 
$encryptedData = base64_encode($encrypted);
```

Need to implement same functionality in c# please Give some solutions

Thank You